# Webpack-stream: How to use array of configs?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

If I use `webpack` via CLI I am able to export array of configs:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: {/*entry#1*/},
    target: 'electron-renderer'
    //...
  },
  {
    entry: {/*entry#2*/}
    target: 'webworker'
    //...
  }
];
```

And it works fine. But when I try to pass it via `webpack-stream` in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
const webpack2 = require('webpack');
const webpackConf = require('./webpack.config.js');

...

gulp.task('run webpack', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/app.js') // I use only entry#1 here, cause it should override it via config file... I suppose
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConf, webpack2))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/app'));
});
```

It finishes task without errors but never insert result files into output folder.

If I write `webpackStream(webpackConf[0], webpack2)` or `webpackStream(webpackConf[1], webpack2)` (only one of my configs) it works well.

Comment: Judging from the documentation of *webpack-stream*, it doesn't support arrays of webpack configurations, so I guess you'll have to iterate your array and process each configuration separately

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `webpack-stream`'s [Multi-compiler support](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream#multi-compiler-support).

You really don't even need to `gulp.src` the first entry from your webpack config and can do something like:

```
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
const webpack2 = require('webpack');
const webpackConf = require('./webpack.config.js');

gulp.task('run webpack', () => {
  return webpackStream({config: webpackConf}, webpack2)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/app'));
});
```